# Passing credentials to Safari from iOS app

Tags: ios, http, authentication, safari, xamarin.ios

I am working on an iOS app in Monotouch. Part of it is to connect to an exchange server and download a list of emails. I would like to include the ability to open the email in the OWA client as well (so I don't have to recreate a email client to provide features OWA gives me for free).

I don't want the user to have to input credentials again however. Opening OWA in safari would usually present the user with either a form or a pop up asking for username and password.

Say I have a user `admin` with password `password1`. Currently what I do is request safari to open a link in the following form:

`https://admin:password1@mailserver/exchange`

This passes the credentials to safari and bypasses the HTTP basic authentication that OWA would usually pop up, however it is not very safe and safari complains of a possible phishing attack.

What other options are there for performing this kind of bypass of HTTP basic authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using HttpWebRequest to download each page and set the UIWebView's text manually.  Using HttpWebRequest gives you the flexibility to use whatever cookies, credentials, http headers, etc. you want.

This will be tricky, but probably the only way to safely get the credentials in there.  Not sure if your OWA app will be able to handle it either.

Comment: wouldn't this cause issues with clicking on links inside the UIWebView?

Comment: You can get an event when navigating (and cancel it) and perform requests yourself.   I have done this with an existing app.